# Objective C. Casting int to float

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point, int

Sorry for such general question, but what is the best (as fast as possible and most safety) method to convert int to float in ObjC:

**First**

```
int b = 10;
float a = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: b] floatValue]
```

There will be `NSNumber` instance and messages `numberWithInt`, `floatValue` will be send, right?

**Second**

```
int b = 10;
float a = (float) b;
```

*C-style: this with call some subroutine?*

**Or some another way?**

And why?

Comment: Use the cast. It does not call a subroutine. The compiler will make sure the correct assembly code is used.

Comment: Don't use the cast. A plain `float a = b;` suffices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C-style type cast is the clearest and easiest to read. If I happened to find code that created an `NSNumber` object just to have it do the conversion, it would leave me wondering "Why did he do it that way? Is something happening here other than a plain old type conversion? What am I missing?"

As for speed, I suspect that the simple type conversion would also be faster - the `NSNumber` object will need to perform pretty much the same operations to do the conversion, and has the additional overhead of object creation and messaging on top of that. But as in all such cases, don't guess - measure. Profile your code to see if the conversion is a bottleneck that's significant enough to be worthy of your attention.

Comment: I just want to fill the `CGRect` struct about 10 times and found I dont know how to convert with the best way

Comment: The question then is, fill it with what? If you're filling them with literal hard-coded values, you can simply write `NSMakeRect(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`, with no conversion necessary. On the other hand, if you're reading data from a plist, you're going to get an NSNumber object anyway, so just call its `-floatValue` method. Type casting the return value from `-intValue` would accomplish nothing but pointless obfuscation. The simplest way is almost always the best.

Comment: I am doing it in `for` cycle from I get int value and pass this into `CGRect` struct

Comment: Then just use a type cast. It's the clearest and easiest to read, and if you're only doing it ten times there's absolutely *no* reason to waste time trying to "optimize" it.

Answer (score 5):

Since you ask about safety, the first thing you need to check is whether the value of your `int` fits in a `float`. Otherwise you're silently losing data. Unless the value is pretty small, it won't fit. I would switch to using `double` so you don't have to worry about this, then just make the assignment:

```
double d;
d = i;
```

There is rarely any use for variables of type `float`, much like `short`...

Comment: -1 The maximum value for a float is _much_ larger than the maximum value for an int. The max for a float is defined as 3.40282347 x 10^38 while the max for an int is defined as 2147483647 which makes the max value for a float 1.58456316 × 10^29 times larger

Comment: @nick: Just because the maximum value is larger does not mean that any `int` fits in a `float`. A `float` (IEEE single precision) only has 24 value bits for the mantissa. This means if an integer is larger than 2^24-1, it only fits in a float if the low bits are all zero. That is, `0x1fffffe` fits but `0x1ffffff` does not. If you don't believe me, try converting the latter to a float and back and you'll see that the value has changed. (If you're on x86 with GCC, be sure to use `-ffloat-store` or it might not actually convert.)

Comment: You're right, I never knew that and I apologize, but it did seem a little odd to me. I'm trying to remove the -1, but it tells me that the vote is locked in :(

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see the need for an `NSNumber` object when a direct typecast between two numeric primitives is available. The `NSNumber` class was not meant solely for type conversion anyway.